# How to write multiple statments in select method of lambda expressions

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I'm trying to prepare an XML document using XDocument at the same time I'm adding items to a specific Dictionary, but I struck with below error.

The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

and the Code snippet is

```
Dictionary<string, string> userguid = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    XDocument XMLDoc =
                new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                new XElement("NewDataSet",
                  new XElement("Users",
                      new XElement("UserID", userid),
                      new XElement("FullName", "anyone"),
                      new XElement("UserName", "anyone"),
                      new XElement("Password", 123),
                      new XElement("Description", "anyone"),
                      new XElement("DomainName", string.Empty),
                      new XElement("Mailbox_Size", 20),
                      new XElement("Enabled", "True"),
                      new XElement("Permissions", 14),
                      new XElement("CreationTime", "2011-07-19T17:45:58.53125+05:30")
                      ),
                userNames.Select((item, value) =>
                   {
                       new XElement("Users",
                          new XElement("UserID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")),
                          new XElement("FullName", item.Trim()),
                          new XElement("UserName", item.Trim()),
                          new XElement("Password", passwords[value].Trim()),
                          new XElement("Description", item.Trim()),
                          new XElement("DomainName", string.Empty),
                          new XElement("Mailbox_Size", 20),
                          new XElement("Enabled", "True"),
                          new XElement("Permissions", 14),
                          new XElement("CreationTime", "2011-07-19T17:45:58.53125+05:30"));
                        userguid.Add(userid, emailAddresses[value].Trim());
                   }
                        )
                      ));
```

Comment: what `Type` is `userNames`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost doing it right, but when using a statement block (`{…}`) you need to explicitly `return` a suitable value because `Select` takes a delegate that returns a value.

(Remember, the abbreviated single expression lambda:

```
x => expr(x)
```

is really just short for the fuller version:

```
x => { return expr(x); }
```

)

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm scratching my head from yesterday you have solved my problem in a sec

Answer (score 1):

when you are using a block instead of a lambda (in select method i mean), you should return the result. i mean `userNames.Select((item, value) => { /* return the result here... */ });`:

```
Dictionary<string, string> userguid = new Dictionary<string, string>();

XDocument XMLDoc =
    new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
        new XElement(
            "NewDataSet",
            new XElement(
                "Users",
                new XElement("UserID", userid),
                new XElement("FullName", "anyone"),
                new XElement("UserName", "anyone"),
                new XElement("Password", 123),
                new XElement("Description", "anyone"),
                new XElement("DomainName", string.Empty),
                new XElement("Mailbox_Size", 20),
                new XElement("Enabled", "True"),
                new XElement("Permissions", 14),
                new XElement("CreationTime", "2011-07-19T17:45:58.53125+05:30")
                ),
            userNames.Select(
                             (item, value) =>{
                                 userguid.Add(userid, emailAddresses[value].Trim());
                                 return new XElement(
                                     "Users",
                                     new XElement("UserID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")),
                                     new XElement("FullName", item.Trim()),
                                     new XElement("UserName", item.Trim()),
                                     new XElement("Password", passwords[value].Trim()),
                                     new XElement("Description", item.Trim()),
                                     new XElement("DomainName", string.Empty),
                                     new XElement("Mailbox_Size", 20),
                                     new XElement("Enabled", "True"),
                                     new XElement("Permissions", 14),
                                     new XElement("CreationTime", "2011-07-19T17:45:58.53125+05:30"));
                             }
                )
            ));
```